# Showing that if a function is continuous at x=0, that it is continuous at every point

Tags: general-topology, optimization

Question: Let $f:$ $\mathbb{R}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function which satisfies $f(x+y)= f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that if $f$ is continuous at $x =0$ that it is continuous at every point. Also show that if it vanishes at a single point of $\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ vanishes at every point of $\mathbb{R}$.

Attempt:

$$\begin{align*}
&f(0)=f(0)f(0)\Rightarrow f(0)=2f(0)\Rightarrow f(0)=0\\
&f(0)=f(x-x)=f(x+(-x))=f(x)+f(-x)\Rightarrow f(x)+f(-x)=0\\
&\quad\Rightarrow f(-x)=-f(x)
\end{align*}$$

This is what I have so,far, but I am unsure if this will be acceptable as I am trying to use Euclidean topology. That aside, where do I take this next? Moreover, how do I prove the vanishing portion of the question?

Comment: Sorry in advance about formatting, I am still figuring out the interworkings of LaTeX.

Comment: In the second line of implications you want $f(x+(-x))=f(x)f(-x)$: you were thinking of additive functions, but this one satisfies a different condition.

Comment: I see where you are going with this, but does that I validate my third line then? Moreover, what do I from there on out? This problem is really taxing my abilities as this is my first time doing optimization theory.

Comment: It’s simply not true that $f(x+(-x))=f(x)+f(-x)$, so everything that depends on that step is invalid. You made the same mistake in your first calculation: $f(0)f(0)=f(0)^2$, not $2f(0)$, so $f(0)= . . .\;$?

Comment: $f(0)$=0 no? Then I need to take $f(x+(-x))^2$

Comment: No, from $f(0)^2=f(0)$ all that you can infer is that $f(0)$ is either $0$ or $1$. If $f(0)=0$, you can show that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, but you should look at $f(x+0)$, not at $f(x+(-x))$; there is no reason to look at $f(x+(-x))$ at all.

Answer (score 1):

For the first, $$\lim_{h\to0}f(x+h)=f(x)\lim_{h\to 0}f(h)=f(x)f(0)=f(x).$$
For the second, if $f(a)=0$ then 
$$f(x)=f(x-a+a)=f(x-a)f(a)=0. $$

Comment: So how does the first line prove it is continuous at 0, it’s continuous elsewhere. Finally, for the second portion is that all I would need to prove the vanishing portion? It seems like I would need to prove more than that no?

Comment: @Tony456: There are a few details to be added, but the answer is basically complete. The first line shows the main steps in a proof that if $f$ is continuous at $0$, it’s continuous everywhere: the second equality follows from continuity of $f$ at $0$, and the conclusion that $\lim_{h\to 0}f(x+h)=f(x)$ is precisely continuity of $f$ at $x$. The last line is a proof that if $f(a)=0$, then $f(x)=0$ for an arbitrary $x\in\Bbb R$, i.e., that $f$ is identically $0$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott how can apply this to prove the vanishing aspect?

Comment: @Tony456: It **is** the vanishing aspect. When we say that a function $f$ vanishes at every point of $\Bbb R$, we simply mean that $f(x)=0$ for every $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. You have helped me more than you know!